# Trying to update the array in mongo data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update/add a field in array of data collection record.

```
    { _id: 5f172788d775fa49dc0abe63,
      filter_count: 5,
      batch_key: '187aa0b2-f8b7-4b6a-8bd3-4d2df288e673',
      report_id: '5f0ffbcdd67d70c1a3b143aa',
      filters:
       [ { _id: 5f17278bd775fa49dc0abe64,
           name: 'USER 2 cards filter',
           id: '5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7',
           origin: 'USER' },
         { _id: 32334355fa49dc0abe545645,
           name: 'USER 1 cards filter',
           id: 'drdeseadasda3b143e34sad',
           origin: 'STUDENT' } ],
      __v: 0,
      file_count: 1 }
```

Above is the data I have, Now I am trying to add one field at filters, array with matching `id`
but its not happening with below code.

```
   const result = await execute_model.findByIdAndUpdate(
                _id, 
                { "filters.id" : id{
                    $set:
                    {
                        status: 'SUCCESS'
                        info: 'SUCCESSFULLY CREATED'
                    }
                }
                }, {new: true});
```

`_id` would be `5f172788d775fa49dc0abe63`

`id` would be(which would be in array of filters in `5f17278bd775fa49dc0abe64`)

So for example when I pass the above `_id` and `id` the expected result is below

```
 { _id: 5f172788d775fa49dc0abe63,
      filter_count: 5,
      batch_key: '187aa0b2-f8b7-4b6a-8bd3-4d2df288e673',
      report_id: '5f0ffbcdd67d70c1a3b143aa',
      filters:
       [ { _id: 5f17278bd775fa49dc0abe64,
           name: 'USER 2 cards filter',
           id: '5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7',
           origin: 'USER',
           status: 'SUCCESS',
           info: 'SUCCESSFULLY CREATED'
         },
         { _id: 32334355fa49dc0abe545645,
           name: 'USER 1 cards filter',
           id: 'drdeseadasda3b143e34sad',
           origin: 'STUDENT' } ],
      __v: 0,
      file_count: 1 }
```

Not sure why its not happening, can anyone help me here. with setting the right query?

Edit- model

```
 report_id:{type:String,trim:true},
    file_name:{type:String},
    filters:[{
        status:{type:String}, // Trying to add this
            id:{type:String},
          info:{type:String}, // Also this
          name:{type:String},
        origin:{type:String}
     }],

batch_key:{type:String,trim:true},
file_count:{type:Number},
filter_count:{type:Number},
 executed_time:{type:Date}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `execute_model` to see if that model has the fields `status` and `info` else it wont update.
Example.

```
const execute_model = new Schema(
    {
        filter_count: Number,
        batch_key: String,
        report_id: String,
        filters:[{name:String, status: 'String', info:'String', origin:'String' }]
}
```

So you need the fields in Schema else it will be ignored.

One option is you find one

```
const data = await execute_model.find({ _id }).limit(1);
```

Now you have the whole data. Now update data with javascript array methods and update the mongo in one shot.

```
const newData = await execute_model.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: data[0].id },
                    { filter_count: 5,
      batch_key: '187aa0b2-f8b7-4b6a-8bd3-4d2df288e673',
      report_id: '5f0ffbcdd67d70c1a3b143aa',
      filters:
       [ { _id: 5f17278bd775fa49dc0abe64,
           name: 'USER 2 cards filter',
           id: '5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7',
           origin: 'USER',
           status: 'SUCCESS',
           info: 'SUCCESSFULLY CREATED'
         },
         { _id: 32334355fa49dc0abe545645,
           name: 'USER 1 cards filter',
           id: 'drdeseadasda3b143e34sad',
           origin: 'STUDENT' } ],
      __v: 0,
      file_count: 1 }
                )
```

Comment: I want to add that 2(`status` and `info`) things in that array where I found `id`

Comment: can you add the code for the execute_model as well.

Comment: Added model to the question

Comment: Yes Velu, I already have those fields but can you check `findByIdAndUpdate` thing, I thing the problem is there

Comment: I tried few of this array methods, do check out too if you find any useful that could help
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: But I want this dynamic, Not static like you did. I am passing it from a function  to update this `status` and `info` to update. What you did is static. Where I am looking for a query which dynamically finds the logic of where `_id` and find `id` from array and add `status` and `info`